# Программно задать ОС приложению или WebView

Tags: android, windows, ios, macos, webview

есть *js-скрипты, которые могут узнать какой ОС пользуется клиент (windows, mac, android, etc)
можно ли как-то для WebView в Android задать (читать как "обмануть") нужную ОС для  таких скриптов?
сказать что самое приложение или самое WebView использует не Android, а Windows или iPhone ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Возможно эти параметры задаются в `UserAgent` (но без примера такого js эта информация не точна), обычно там пишется браузер и устройство, вот [пример для iphone](https://deviceatlas.com/blog/list-of-user-agent-strings#iphone) и вот еще [списки UserAgent](https://developers.whatismybrowser.com/useragents/explore/)

В WebView есть метод `setUserAgentString` для WebSettings:

```
webView.getSettings().setUserAgentString("my-user-agent");
```

Comment: Здесь пример скрипта для получения информации об ОС и браузере: https://stackoverflow.com/a/18706818